# On Implementing the foursquare api for login through foursquare. Unable to get user data

Tags: ios

On Implementing the foursquare api for login through foursquare. How do i get user data after login on safari. I get access token after return back to my app. I implement Foursquare API v2 for iOS using pod.

Answer (score 0):

implement Four Square API key

## write below code in Appdelegate.m File

```
 //Integarate FourSquare
    NSString *yourClientId = @"WSTKVX3HJDWNZHEGZT3PLJQZNP5DUBDIEEUJZC2WVTOXRVWN";
    NSString *yourClientSecret = @"R1BR2I5DCSLYNDO1BIGIFNJFMO5SOLOL12WNAPO3FZVIF0Z2";
    NSString *yourCallbackURl = @"http://www.TestApp.com/Tapp"; //yourapp://foursquare

    [UXRFourSquareNetworkingEngine registerFourSquareEngineWithClientId:yourClientId andSecret:yourClientSecret andCallBackURL:yourCallbackURl];
    self.fourSquareEngine = [UXRFourSquareNetworkingEngine sharedInstance];
```

## Write Below method to get category from FolurSquare Api

```
 -(void)fetchCategoryDataFromFourSquare
    {
        MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        hud.labelText = @"";
        [ApplicationDelegate.fourSquareEngine getCategoriesWithCompletionBlock:^(NSDictionary *dictCategoryInfo)
         {
             NSArray *arr =  [dictCategoryInfo objectForKey:@"categories"];
             mutArrCategoryData = [arr mutableCopy];
             [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
             [tblView reloadData];
         } failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
         {
             [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
             NSLog(@"%@",error);
         }];

    }
```

## Get Vanue Detail

```
    [ApplicationDelegate.fourSquareEngine getVeuneDetail:_strVenueID withCompletionBlock:^(NSDictionary *dictNearbyData)
    {
        [self setDetailsWithInfo:[dictNearbyData objectForKey:@"venue"]];
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
     {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
//        NSLog(@"%@",error);
     }];
```

## Get Near by Location

```
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=%@&key=%@&sensor=false&maxwidth=320", photoRef, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];


    [ApplicationDelegate.fourSquareEngine getNearLocation:loc withCompletionBlock:^(NSDictionary *dictNearbyData)
    {
        NSArray *arr = [dictNearbyData objectForKey:@"venues"];
        if([arr count]!=0)
        {
            NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"location.distance" ascending:YES];

            NSMutableArray *tempArray = [arr mutableCopy];
            [tempArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];

            for(int i=0;i<[tempArray count];i++)
            {
                if([[[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"location.distance"] intValue] < 804.5)
                {
                    [mutArrNearByLocationData addObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:i]];
                }
            }

            // ----- Add predicate for check whose distance is less than 0.5 miles (804.5 meters)
//            NSPredicate *DistancePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"distance <= 804.5"];
//            NSArray *LoyaltyfilteredAry = [mutArrNearByLocationData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:DistancePredicate];

            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
            [tblView reloadData];
        }
        else
        {
            showAlertView(@"No locations within 0.5 miles");
        }

        //[self showNearByPlaceOnMap:mutArrNearByLocationData];
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
    {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];
```